# How can I view the list of my questions that were undeleted on a given SE site?

Tags: support, undelete

I wonder if there is a way to view the list of my questions that were undeleted on a given SE site.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1814456?UserId=18147)

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , score
     , posttypeid
     , ph.creationdate [ Undeleted on]
     , p.creationdate
from posts p
inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = p.id
where ph.posthistorytypeid = 13 -- undelete
and p.owneruserid = ##userid##
```

when run today, this is your result on WebApps:

[image: query result showing three rows with undeleted posts]

Note that the query might return posts more than once. This will happen for posts that couldn't decide on being deleted or undeleted (aka got deleted and undeleted more than once).

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the fine [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the admirable [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).